# Basic Shape recognition (openCV C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I have a project that I need to make for classes and I chose task that is a bit out of my skills.
Target is to count result of dice rolls.
For now, I'am trying to make it work on a sample pic:

[sample pic of dices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/920Co.jpg)

[image]

and my current code is added below:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat KostkaFunkcja(Mat image, Mat in, Scalar low, Scalar high);
int getMaxAreaContourId(vector <vector<cv::Point>> contours);
vector<Point> contoursConvexHull(vector<vector<Point> > contours, int index);
Mat ZnakiFunkcja(Mat image, Mat in, Scalar low, Scalar high);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("kostki.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if (!image.data)
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat imgHSV;
    Mat workimage = image;

    cvtColor(workimage, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV
    //red dice
    workimage = KostkaFunkcja(workimage, imgHSV, Scalar(146, 0, 31), Scalar(179, 255, 255));
    //green dice
    workimage = KostkaFunkcja(workimage, imgHSV, Scalar(25, 147, 0), Scalar(98, 255, 154));
    //yellow dice
    workimage = KostkaFunkcja(workimage, imgHSV, Scalar(22, 45, 161), Scalar(91, 255, 255));
    //black dice
    workimage = KostkaFunkcja(workimage, imgHSV, Scalar(98, 0, 0), Scalar(179, 232, 107));
    //white symbols
    workimage = ZnakiFunkcja(workimage, imgHSV, Scalar(58, 0, 183), Scalar(179, 145, 255));
    namedWindow("Kostki_kontur", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Kostki_kontur", workimage);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;

}

Mat KostkaFunkcja(Mat image, Mat in, Scalar low, Scalar high)
{
    Mat temp;
    inRange(in, low, high, temp);
    erode(temp, temp, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    dilate(temp, temp, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    dilate(temp, temp, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    erode(temp, temp, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

    Mat srcBlur, srcCanny;
    blur(temp, srcBlur, Size(3, 3));

    Canny(srcBlur, srcCanny, 0, 100, 3, true);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(srcCanny, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    int largest_contour_index = getMaxAreaContourId(contours);

    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(srcCanny.size(), CV_8UC3);

    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(255, 255, 255);
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2);
    }

    vector<Point> ConvexHullPoints = contoursConvexHull(contours, largest_contour_index);
    polylines(image, ConvexHullPoints, true, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    return image;
}

vector<Point> contoursConvexHull(vector<vector<Point> > contours, int index)
{
    vector<Point> result;
    vector<Point> pts;
    for (size_t j = 0; j< contours[index].size(); j++)
        pts.push_back(contours[index][j]);
    convexHull(pts, result);
    return result;
}

int getMaxAreaContourId(vector <vector<cv::Point>> contours)
{
    double maxArea = 0;
    int maxAreaContourId = -1;
    for (int j = 0; j < contours.size(); j++) {
        double newArea = cv::contourArea(contours.at(j));
        if (newArea > maxArea) {
            maxArea = newArea;
            maxAreaContourId = j;
        }
        return maxAreaContourId;
    }
}
Mat ZnakiFunkcja(Mat image, Mat in, Scalar low, Scalar high)
{
    Mat temp;
    inRange(in, low, high, temp);
    erode(temp, temp, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    dilate(temp, temp, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    dilate(temp, temp, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    erode(temp, temp, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

    Mat srcBlur, srcCanny;
    blur(temp, srcBlur, Size(3, 3));

    Canny(srcBlur, srcCanny, 0, 100, 3, true);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(srcCanny, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(srcCanny.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(255, 255, 255);
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2);
        polylines(image, contours, true, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        return image;
    }

}
```

Yet I have no idea how to count different shapes (hearts, lightnings, shields, numbers).

I will be greatfull if anybody would give me a tip or solution of how to do the job.

1) sorry for bad english
2) we had no openCV in classes [only basic  c++]
3) tryed to found anything usefull on internet, but even if I found anything, I could't understand what was happening in the code

Comment: The simplest would be to store 'GrayScaled' versions/images of the symbols you are looking to count. The dice can be found using the algorithm you are using now and then either you can run [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html) to find if any of the stored symbols are present in the image. This would be difficult when the image quality/perspective/aspect ratio changes.

Comment: It would be helpful to give the functions english names so it is easier to understand what their purpose is.

Comment: @RickM - what about rotation? As I reed what you linked it "force" matches template with the image. So I guess it will not match if symbol on pic is rotated. Am I correct?
Could I also use transform perspective and rotation to export dice and position it "horizontaly" before matching? if yes, any easy way to do it?

Comment: @OskarŁukianowicz Yeah for rotation and size changes it will not work. In that case, either you can do what you suggested but I think that task isn't easy. You can either use [HOG features](https://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/) or you can use [Feature detectors and descriptors](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your project can be splited in three steps:

1. find the dices.
2. extract the shapes from the visible face of
   the dices.
3. count the faces.

For the first step among all the possible approaches I think saliency map approaches can help.
Saliency map are a family of segmentation algorithm that aim to detect the parts in the image which are more likely to attract visual attention.

OpenCV have a saliency API that already implement several saliency algorithm and for each of them you can get an segmentation map.

It is highlikely considering the example image you gave the saliency will be focus on the dices.

From this you can so extract the dices as rois from the original image.

For the step 2) saliency algorithms may also fit... or not that depend a lot of the statistical criterions that are used by the algorithm.
However the previously extracted rois should only contain the face of the dice that does contain the shapes you want to count in step 3) so approaches based on contours detection may give quite good result.

Once you get the shapes among the way to count each shape you can use templateMatching (that is also already implement in OpenCV),a clustering approach based on the a shape sensitive metric (Hausdorff, Dice, ...), or many other.

Here is a code that can help you to deal with the two first step.

```
#ifndef _DEBUG
#define _DEBUG
#endif

#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/saliency.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#include <list>

CV_EXPORTS_W void get_regions_of_interest(cv::InputArray _src, cv::OutputArrayOfArrays mv, cv::OutputArrayOfArrays mv2 = cv::noArray());

int main()
{
    cv::Mat tmp = cv::imread("C:\Desktop\dices.jpg");

    if(!tmp.empty())
    {
        cv::imshow("source",tmp);
        cv::waitKey(-1);
    }

    std::vector<cv::Mat> rois;

    get_regions_of_interest(tmp,rois);

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void get_regions_of_interest(cv::InputArray _src, cv::OutputArrayOfArrays _rois, cv::OutputArrayOfArrays _contours)
{

    // Check that the first argument is an image and the second a vector of images.
    CV_Assert(_src.isMat() && !_src.depth() && (_src.channels() == 1 || _src.channels() == 3) && _rois.isMatVector() && (!_contours.needed() || (_contours.needed() && _contours.isMatVector()) ) );

    static cv::Ptr<cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual> saliency;

    if(!saliency)
        saliency = cv::saliency::StaticSaliencySpectralResidual::create();

    cv::Mat src = _src.getMat();
    cv::Mat gray;

    if(src.depth() == src.type())
        gray = src;
    else
        cv::cvtColor(src,gray,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    bool is_ctr_needed = _contours.needed();
    std::list<cv::Mat> final_ctrs;

    // Step 1) Process the saliency in order to segment the dices.

    cv::Mat saliency_map;
    cv::Mat binary_map;

    saliency->computeSaliency(src,saliency_map);
    saliency->computeBinaryMap(saliency_map,binary_map);


    saliency_map.release();

    // Step 2) From the binary map get the regions of interest.

    cv::Mat1i stats;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> rois;

    cv::Mat labels;
    cv::Mat centroids;

    cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(binary_map, labels, stats, centroids);


    labels.release();
    centroids.release();

    // prepare the memory
    rois.reserve(stats.rows-1);

// Sort the stats in order to remove the background.

    stats = stats.colRange(0,stats.cols-1);

    // Extract the rois.

    for(int i=0;i<stats.rows;i++)
    {
        cv::Rect roi = *reinterpret_cast<cv::Rect*>(stats.ptr<int>(i));

        if(static_cast<std::size_t>(roi.area()) == gray.total())
            continue;

        rois.push_back(gray(roi));
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cv::imshow("roi_"+std::to_string(i),gray(roi));
#endif
    }



    // Step 3) Refine.

    // Because the final number of shape cannot be determine in advance it is better to use a linked list than a vector.
    // In practice except if there is a huge number of elements to work with the performance will be almost the same.
    std::list<cv::Mat> shapes;

    int cnt=0;
    for(const cv::Mat& roi : rois)
    {

        cv::Mat tmp = roi.clone();

        // Slightly sharpen the regions contours
        cv::morphologyEx(tmp,tmp, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, cv::noArray());
        // Reduce the influence of local unhomogeneous illumination.
        cv::GaussianBlur(tmp,tmp,cv::Size(31,31), 5);

        cv::Mat thresh;
        // Binarize the image.
        cv::threshold(roi,thresh,0.,255.,cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);
#ifdef _DEBUG
        cv::imshow("thresh"+std::to_string(cnt++),thresh);
#endif
        // Find the contours of each sub region on interest
        std::vector<cv::Mat> contours;

        cv::findContours(thresh, contours, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        cv::Mat dc;

        cv::merge(std::vector<cv::Mat>(3,thresh),dc);

//        cv::drawContours(dc, contours,-1,cv::Scalar(0.,0.,255),2);
//        cv::imshow("ctrs"+std::to_string(cnt),dc);

        // Extract the sub-regions

        if(is_ctr_needed)
        {
            for(const cv::Mat& ctrs: contours)
            {

                cv::Rect croi = cv::boundingRect(ctrs);

                // If the sub region is to big or to small it is depreate
                if(static_cast<std::size_t>(croi.area()) == roi.total() || croi.area()<50)
                    continue;

                final_ctrs.push_back(ctrs);

                shapes.push_back(roi(croi));

#ifdef _DEBUG
                cv::rectangle(dc,croi,cv::Scalar(0.,0.,255.));

                cv::imshow("sub_roi_"+std::to_string(cnt++),roi(croi));
#endif
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(const cv::Mat& ctrs: contours)
            {

                cv::Rect croi = cv::boundingRect(ctrs);

                // If the sub region is to big or to small it is depreate
                if(static_cast<std::size_t>(croi.area()) == roi.total() || croi.area()<50)
                    continue;

                shapes.push_back(roi(croi));

#ifdef _DEBUG
                cv::rectangle(dc,croi,cv::Scalar(0.,0.,255.));

                cv::imshow("sub_roi_"+std::to_string(cnt++),roi(croi));
#endif

            }
        }

    }
#ifdef _DEBUG
    cv::waitKey(-1);
#endif

    // Final Step: set the output

    _rois.create(shapes.size(),1,CV_8U);
    _rois.assign(std::vector<cv::Mat>(shapes.begin(),shapes.end()));

    if(is_ctr_needed)
    {
        _contours.create(final_ctrs.size(),1,CV_32SC2);
        _contours.assign(std::vector<cv::Mat>(final_ctrs.begin(), final_ctrs.end()));
    }

}
```

Comment: TY for anwser!
Wow... that's a lot of information... I guess I will look into it tomorow, but on the first look, I dont understand most of it.

Comment: I can understand. I check the code I gave to you works so you can make it work and take a look to the different imshow outputs it will be easier than just reading the code.

Comment: First problem is that when I tryed to run your code, I've got an error:
1>c:\users\user\desktop\kostki\kostki\kostki\main.cpp(9): fatal error C1083: Nie można otworzyć pliku dołącz: 'opencv2/saliency.hpp': No such file or directory
I'am using latest OpenCV from their website, is there anything special I need to do, to use #include <opencv2/saliency.hpp> ?

Comment: Have you compiled the opencv_contrib modules ?

Comment: As you can see here: 
https://github.com/opencv
OpenCV is mainly compose of 4 git hub.
OpenCV contains the general version of the library, OpenCV_contrib contains some extra modules, OpenCV_extra is just some databases of images that can be helpfull for some application and are needed for some contrib modules.
CVAT is an image and video annotation tool.

Comment: @OskarŁukianowicz In the tags you should add shape-recognition and object-recognition

Comment: sry had problemes with my PC.
Ive used self extracting file that is downloadable at OpenCV website

Comment: For my information do you (or your institution) own the dice on the picture ? I mean the objective of your task is to count only the visible faces visible in that picture ? to count the visible no matter for any launch ? to count the face for any kind of dice ?